# KineticJS selective 'get'

Tags: kineticjs, sprite

How can I select all the shapes/sprites in a layer who have certain characteristics?

For example all the shapes that have a certain x or y position, or those who have certain properties?

I would like to be able to loop through all of the sprites in my game who have specific characteristics and do stuff with them.

For example can I do something like:

```
  // loop through the 'alien' sprites, selecting dead ones only up front.
  var deadAliens = layer.get('alien','shield==0')
  deadAliens.each(function(deadAlien) {
     deadAlien.remove(); // remove dead alien
  });
```

Instead of:

```
  // loop through 'alien' sprites and use 'if' statements to select dead ones.
  var aliens = layer.get('alien') 
  aliens.each(function(alien) {
     if (alien.getAttr('shield')==0) alien.remove(); // remove dead alien
  });
```

The point being I want to perform the selection with the 'get' rather than use 'if' statements within the loop.

Edit:
Even better would be something like:

```
layer.get('*[search criteria]*').remove();
```

...which applies the `remove()` method to the selection directly. This would be neater than my first example above.

Thanks

Owen

Comment: You can write your own custom `get` method for this and attach it to `Layer` object using `addMethods(constructor, methods)` function. (http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Util.html). The logic (i.e your `Instead of` part) ultimately has to go somewhere

Comment: I don't think your first example will give you much better performance than the 2nd example anyways, but it does look cleaner I guess haha

Comment: Yes indeed, but my thought was that in standard JQuery you can apply methods to entire sets of DOM elements based on their class.  I guess I was hoping for a Canvas equivalent for my Sprite objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer your question, currently you have to take the second approach that you mentioned, which is to use the each method(), and check the properties of each result.  KineticJS may support comparator functions in the future if there's enough demand from the community.